# How does electricity travel near the speed of light if electrons drift at a snail pace?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, speed-of-light, electric-current

I was in a reddit argument with someone who said electrons didn't flow at the speed of light in a circuit. Then he linked the Wikipedia page for drift velocity and defeated me in one fell swoop. Now, my entire understanding of electricity and electrons has been thrown upside down. I thought that electron flow in a circuit was essentially like pushing a chain of balls that each bounce off each other, and since electrons travel near the speed of light, this was why electricity was nearly instantaneous in a circuit. But, it seems that the electrons simply carry the electromagnetic wave coming from the power source by use of their own electrical field. Since electromagnetic waves can travel at the speed of light, is this how the effects of electricity travel independently of the electron drift velocity?

Comment: A train doesn't travel at the speed of light but the instance the first carriage moves, the last one follows almost immediately. Electricity is like a moving train in a way.

Comment: The electric force between electrons moves at the speed of light, so if one electron moves, the next one starts moving almost instantaneously, and so on down the wire.

Comment: have a  look  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html  and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html#c1  and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/Fermi.html#c1 and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html#c1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the electric bulb turns on almost instantly when the switch is closed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80926/)

Comment: "Pushing a chain of balls" wasn't quite too far off the mark. The trick is realizing that it's not the _balls_ that matter so much as the _push_ that matters, and how and how fast _that_ (or more properly, the disturbance or _wave_ generated thereby) travels down the line of balls. The push, after all, is the actual energy; the balls are just a medium for the transport thereof.